# PrimeFaces AccordionPanel with paginator

Tags: primefaces, accordion, panel, paginator

I'm trying to implement paginator (or something like these) with accordionPanel in PrimeFaces, There is  not a single example present in primefaces demo website,I searched in web as well,Is it possible to implement paginator with accordionPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want paginator in `accordionPanel` then sorry, it's not possible. However if you are trying to implement `datatable` inside `accordionPanel` and in that if you want paginator then it's possible. I am pretty sure there is example present of `datatable` as well as `accordionPanel` you need to combine them it should work.